# How does the cnx gate work in Qiskit (Python)?

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, qiskit

Could somebody explain the cnx operator, and how it operates on its qubit parameters to flip the target qubit in Qiskit (Python)?

Comment: Could you explain what the function CNX is? It is not immediately obvious what you mean.

Comment: it's CX with many control qbits C(N)X

Comment: Check ~p. 180 in Nielsen and Chuang (10th edition).

Comment: Are you asking for implementation details or for a comprehensive explanation of what does the $C^n(X)$ gate?

Comment: Implementation details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `cnx` says [`Control n-1 qubits, apply 'not' to last one`](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/47a0a30949f41c7cf901d5562b225e7fc8f45c21/community/games/game_engines/composite_gates.py#L58).

So basically $C^n(X)$ in Qiskit is defined like $$C^n(X)|x_1\cdots x_{n-1}\rangle|\psi\rangle = |x_1\cdots x_{n-1}\rangle X^{x_1\cdots x_{n-1}}|\psi\rangle$$ where $x_1\cdots x_{n-1}$ in the exponent of $U$ means the *product* of the bits $x_1,\cdots, x_{n-1}$. That is, the [Pauli-X gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Pauli-X_gate) gate gets applied to the $n$-th qubit $|\psi\rangle$ only when all of the first $n-1$ bits are $1$.

Comment: You misinterpreted the documentation I guess. The line only means "we apply X controlled by $n-1$ other qubits"

Comment: @Nelimee Hi! Erm, I'm not sure that recurrence is correct. You mean the $X$ gate will now get applied to the (n-1)-th qubit in case $x_1\cdots x_{n-2}$ is $1$? That doesn't seem like it; check page 180 of N&C for instance.

Comment: OK, read too quickly, you are right!