# Order of controls and targets of cnx gates in Qiskit (Python)

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, qiskit

In the following piece of code:

```
cnx(qwc, q[0], q[1],q[2],q[3])
```

in what order control qubits and target qubit are? Which qubit is inverted for which values of which ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6071), if *all* of `q[0]`, `q[1]` and `q[2]` (the n-1 qubits) are 1, then `q[3]` (the n-th qubit) is inverted. That is, `q[3]` is the target qubit and the rest (`q[0]`, `q[1]` and `q[2]`) are controls.